# What's the best approach to implement polling in react-native?

Tags: react-native, polling

The app I am building will be polling the server periodically to determine if the admin disabled the device on the server. When this happens, we abort all requests in progress and immediately “shutdown” the app.

Comment: I think they're implementing WebSocket soon (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/WebSocket) in RN. Meanwhile I'd either search for custom plugin or just use `fetch()` with some interval.